# I have a google sheets cell with 5 different texts (from a dropdown) - how can I make another cell return a value based on the text

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, dropdown, formula

The 5 values in J4 are Studio, 1, 2, 3, 4.
Mortgage! is another sheet where I want to take B2*(52/12) if studio, B3*(52/12) if 1 and so on

Here is what I have been working with. I think I am close I just can't get it together to work

```
If  
$J$4='Studio',(Mortgage!B2*(52/12) 
$J$4='1',(Mortgage!B3*(52/12) 
$J$4='2',(Mortgage!B3*(52/12) 
$J$4='3',(Mortgage!B4*(52/12)
$J$4='4',(Mortgage!B5*(52/12)
```

Comment: Still getting a parse error - tried the ones below. Here is a link to the sheet    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10sg_c7j0CWlTxBYCizZhUTHdwCmtQOJBMPSzocreULU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is acceptable. You need to use the correct syntax.

```
=IF(  
$J$4='Studio',Mortgage!B2*(52/12), 
IF($J$4='1',Mortgage!B3*(52/12), 
IF($J$4='2',Mortgage!B3*(52/12), 
IF($J$4='3',Mortgage!B4*(52/12),
$J$4='4',Mortgage!B5*(52/12)
))))
```

By the way, it is customary to post a link to a public Google Sheet showing sample data when asking questions about Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you have an errory in your sample code as you say `I want to take B2*(52/12) if studio, B3*(52/12) if 1 and so on`, but your sample is doing `(Mortgage!B3*(52/12)` for both `$J$4='1'` and `$J$4='2'`.

Therefor, I will assumne you are instead expecting...

```
if
$J$4='Studio',(Mortgage!B2*(52/12) 
$J$4='1',(Mortgage!B3*(52/12) 
$J$4='2',(Mortgage!B4*(52/12) 
$J$4='3',(Mortgage!B5*(52/12)
$J$4='4',(Mortgage!B6*(52/12)
```

As others suggested, you can achive this by applying a nested `IF()` function with correct syntax,

but other than standard `IF()` funciont, you can use `IFS()` function for these kinds of cases:

```
=IFS(  
$J$4='Studio',Mortgage!B2*(52/12),
$J$4='1',Mortgage!B3*(52/12), 
$J$4='2',Mortgage!B4*(52/12), 
$J$4='3',Mortgage!B5*(52/12),
$J$4='4',Mortgage!B6*(52/12)
)
```

There is also a `SWITCH()` function in google sheet that do similar things:

```
=SWITCH($J$4,
'Studio',Mortgage!B2*(52/12),
'1',Mortgage!B3*(52/12),
'2',Mortgage!B4*(52/12),
'3',Mortgage!B5*(52/12),
'4',Mortgage!B6*(52/12)
)
```

You may even create your own array to lookup for result:

```
=LAMBDA(DATA,
 VLOOKUP($J$4,DATA,2,FALSE)
)({
  'Studio',Mortgag!B2*(52/12);
  '1',Mortgage!B3*(52/12);
  '2',Mortgage!B4*(52/12);
  '3',Mortgage!B5*(52/12);
  '4',Mortgage!B6*(52/12)
 })
```

where the array part:

```
{
  'Studio',Mortgag!B2*(52/12);
  '1',Mortgage!B3*(52/12);
  '2',Mortgage!B4*(52/12);
  '3',Mortgage!B5*(52/12);
  '4',Mortgage!B6*(52/12)
 }
```

can be shortened into something like this:

```
ArrayFormula({{'Studio';'1';'2';'3';'4'},Mortgage!B2:6*(52/12)})
```

or

```
ArrayFormula({{'Studio';TO_TEXT(SEQUENCE(4))},Mortgage!B2:6*(52/12)})
```

Combine this with the `VLOOKUP()`, you get this:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP($J$4,{{'Studio';TO_TEXT(SEQUENCE(4))},Mortgage!B2:6*(52/12)},2,FALSE))
```

`XLOOKUP()` function also works in a similar way as `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP($J$4,{'Studio';TO_TEXT(SEQUENCE(4))},Mortgage!B2:6*(52/12)))
```